# What does the warning message "Selected triggers ..." mean?

Tags: dafny

I got the following warning message, while using the Dafny plugin for VS.  Can anyone explain what it means?

```
Selected triggers: {a[i]} (may loop with "a[i + 1]"). Suppressing loops would leave this expression without triggers.
```

The line in question was

```
assert forall i : int :: 0<=i<a.Length-1 ==> a[i] <= a[i+1] ;
```

Also since this is only a warning message, can I conclude that the verification was otherwise successful?

Comment: Looking at is again.  I think what the first sentence means is something like: "Hey, I decided to use only a[i] as a trigger; I thought about using a[i+1], but decided not to, since that might cause an infinite loop." I'm not sure what the second sentence means.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you're right that if there are no other errors reported, then you can conclude the verification was successful.

The warning has to do with how Z3 (and thus Dafny) handle quantifiers via heuristic pattern-based instantiation. The message is saying that Dafny has decided to select `a[i]` as the trigger (pattern) for this quantifier *even though* it has a so-called "matching loop" with `a[i+1]`. Dafny has decided to do that because it feels it has no other choice for a trigger.

Note that patterns on universal quantifiers are only relevant when *using* the quantified fact later, not when proving it. A universally quantified fact is used by instantiating it on concrete values determined by the pattern. (Dually, patterns on existential quantifiers are only relevant when *proving* them; an existential quantifier is proved by attempting to use values matching the pattern as witnesses.)

A pattern on a universal quantifier causes a matching loop when instantiating the quantifier with a value matching the pattern causes another, different value to be constructed. For your example, the pattern `a[i]` means "any time you have an expression of the form `a[blah]` floating around in the context, try instantiating the quantifier by plugging in `blah` for `a[i]`. Suppose the value `a[0]` is floating around in the context. Then the quantifier will be instantiated at `i == 0` to produce the ground clause

```
0 <= i < a.Length - 1 ==> a[0] <= a[1]
```

This new clause is added to the context, and contains the value `a[1]`, which also matches the pattern. So the solver may instantiate the quantifier again, which will cause the value `a[2]` to be added to the context. This can go on forever and degrade solver performance.

Part of the art of working with tools like Dafny is to engineer formulas to avoid matching loops. One work-around for this formula is to rewrite it as

```
forall i, j :: 0 <= i <= j < a.Length - 1 ==> a[i] <= a[j]
```

Since `<=` is transitive, this is logically equivalent to the previous formula. But it does not have matching loops when the pattern is `{a[i], a[j]}` (there are two quantified variables, so the pattern needs to be extended to contain both of them), since instantiating it with particular values does not create new values that match the pattern.

Another work-around for this formula is

```
forall i, j :: 0 <= i <= j < a.Length - 1 && j == i+1 ==> a[i] <= a[j]
```

This formula is also logically equivalent to the first, because it constrains `j` to be a synonym for `i+1`. While this may seem like a strange way of writing it, it also eliminates the loop.

In fact, modern versions of Dafny will transparently rewrite your original formula into this last one to eliminate the loop and avoid the warning.

Comment: Thanks.  I understand much better now. One thing I learned incidentally from this post is that there is a newer version (2.0.0) on github thant the 1.9.7  version that I got from codeplex.  Since codeplex is soon going readonly, it would be good if someone could rewrite the download page there to pointo the github download page.